# Smart handling of Python array with many indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following piece of code:

```
p1 = np.array([[[[[[[[[[0.]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2)
s = [0]*10
#
# Do something with s
#
p1[s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5],s[6],s[7],s[8],s[9]] += 1
```

Is there a smarter way of:

1. Creating p1 without all those brackets, and
2. Access the components of p1 with a string or a list?

I have in mind something like:

```
p1[s] += 1
```

or:

```
p1[*s] += 1
```

For example, what if instead of 10 indices I wanted N indices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
np.array([[[[[[[[[[0.]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2]*2)
```

is better written as:

```
np.zeros((2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

Or as there are ten `2`s:

```
np.zeros((2,)*10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you also know anything about the second problem?

Comment: For the second problem, with this solution or any other, just use `p1[s]`.  Just make sure that `s` is of the right type, e.g., a tuple here.